# NodeJS: I can't make connect-redis work with express

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

This is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
```

And this is the error I get :

```
  RedisStore.prototype.__proto__ = Store.prototype;
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/cherif/Bureau/Twimbee/server/gamma/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:96:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cherif/Bureau/Twimbee/server/gamma/index.js:2:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Please help

Comment: connect-redis is used for session store. Do you define app.use(express.session({..., store: new RedisStore(...)}); in your app cofiguration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like they've addressed this in their docs:

> Due to express 4.x.x changes, we now need to pass express-session to
>   the function connect-redis exports in order to extend
>   express-session.Store:
>
> var session = require('express-session')
>         , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
>
> app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore(options), secret: 'keyboard
>   cat' }))

https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis under usage

Answer (score 2):

1) remove express from node_modules

2) clean the cache (npm cache clean)

3) install the last version via package.json (*) or npm install

4) install connect-redis via package.json or npm install

5) Use:

,  session = require('express-session') 
 ,  RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation there's something like:

```js
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({client: config.redis.client}),
  secret: 'your key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

And it doesn't get errors with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

also it needs to use resave and saveUninitialized , or you'll get warning message .

```
app.use( session({ 
    store: new RedisStore({ client : yourClient }), 
    secret: 'yourSecretKey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```